# Encrypt CSS style and HTML Is possible?

Tags: html, css, encryption

My scenario is I have created a html website using `inline css` and also used **css generator** tool for **menu items** so any one who have good Idea in design can easily track that style is generated by tool that's why I want encrypt `html` and `css` source after rendering .

please suggest me is there any option to encrypt `html` or `css` code.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Really? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+source+%5Bhtml%5D

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that hide is possible to duplicate but encryption is not related to hide

Comment: Really? ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=encrypt+source+%5Bhtml%5DOR%5Bcss%5D

Comment: @mplungjan can give exact question link which is related to this as i can see they all are different(some question ask how to encrypt file name and most of question about hide html css )

Comment: MANY of them explains how to obfuscate and encrypt and that it is fairly pointless. I can vote to remove the duplicate but really the two searches I posted should convince you

Comment: Well I don't want debate but I think my question is different from above suggested link and I am not agree that my question is duplicate @mplungjan

Comment: I have voted to re-open. The answer is still: if you do not want people to look at your stuff, do not put it on the web

Comment: And my answer is still : encryption of html or css code is not duplicate because I did't get and satisfied question that asked same.

Comment: You cannot encrypt unless you decrypt it for the browser. Same with HTML

Comment: Your question boils down to: how can I hide my HTML/CSS? The answer to which is and always has been and has been repeated many times: **ultimately you can't**, because the browser will have to be able to read it. The only thing you can reasonably do is ***obfuscation*** (also answered many times, search), which is ultimately just as pointless.

Answer (score 1):

no I would say thats not possible.
HTML and CSS are client side code which is open for all to view.
So they can't be encrypted.

Maybe look at minification, but the browser needs to interperate the code so encryption wouldn't be an option.
Here is some links to minify.
https://cssminifier.com
https://javascript-minifier.com/

If your using a CMS there are plently of minification tools.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to encrypt them or suggest me a link related to this.

Comment: Sorry bud, can't encrypt client side code without major problems.
Here is a good read about it.
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm